# ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location

Tags: apache, configuration, proxypass

I tried the answer in this problem.
[How to merge multiple ProxyPass directives in Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/529128/how-to-merge-multiple-proxypass-directives-in-apache)
 But I am getting an error when I am starting apache saying `ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.`

My 000-default.conf has below code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
include location1.conf
include location2.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

and my location1 has,

```
<Location /web/?_escaped_fragment_=/>
ProxyPass        /phpmyadmin !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/
</Location>
```

and my location2 has,

```
<Location /web/#!/>
ProxyPass        /phpmyadmin !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

Answer (score 7):

Similarly as can be seen in the question you mention, there is a necessity to drop the first argument of the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` clauses **when nested under `<Location>` clause**.

So consider altering your config like this:

**location1**:

```
<Location /web/?_escaped_fragment_=/>
    ProxyPass /phpmyadmin !
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8082/          # <== Dropped '/'
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8082/   # <== Dropped '/'
</Location>
```

**location2**:

```
<Location /web/#!/>
    ProxyPass /phpmyadmin !
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/          # <== Dropped '/'
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/   # <== Dropped '/'
</Location>
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. It still complains the same about ` ProxyPass /phpmyadmin !`

Comment: @oussaka Good to hear that :)